# Looking for a configuration server event

Tags: configuration

We are looking for a configuration server event that could tell us about the changes that have been made to the configuration object. We are struggling to get the details on who has changed the object.

Any suggestion would be a great help.

Thanks

Comment: On what platform, in what language, where is your configuration stored? This question can't be answered in its current state.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve found a few Genesys partners have developed Audit Logging applications for Configuration Server changes.
Pointel offers a product called Audit & Alert that can return the user information on changes done. This could actually solve your problem with monitoring change management.

Check this link:
https://www.pointel.com/solutions/cms-audit-alert/